# Blazor Server render pattern in parent-child component relation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to build a Log list that is restarted every time the user press run. I have a parent and a child component, the parent holds a List variable which is passed to the Child as a parameter. The RUN button stays in the parent, and starts the service which will be running.

I've noticed a strange rendering pattern. If I initialize the List in the parent variable before running the service, nothing is rendered on the screen, if I remove the initialization, everything works fine, but the list keeps growing as it is not being cleared.

Probably I am confused about how properties rendering and StateHasChanged works, and I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this for me.

I developed a small example replicating the problem. Sorry, there will be a lot of small pieces of code here, but this is everything you need to do to replicate my problem.

First, create a Blazor Server project, the usual template.

**Add this to NavMenu.razor**

```html
<li class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="list">
        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> List demo
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

**Create two classes, a Messenger and a Service**

```cs
public class Service
{
    Messenger _messenger;
    public Service(Messenger messenger)
    {
        _messenger = messenger;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        await _messenger.AddMessage("test 1");
        await _messenger.AddMessage("test 2");
    }
}

public class Messenger
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public Func<Task> OnMessageAdded { get; set; }

    public async Task AddMessage(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
        await OnMessageAdded?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**Add this in the method ConfigureServices of the Startup.cs class**

```cs
services.AddSingleton<Messenger>();
services.AddSingleton<Service>();
```

**Parent.razor component**

```cs
@page "/list"

@using BlazorApp4.Data

@inject Service service

<h3>List of stuff</h3>

<button @onclick="Run">RUN</button>
<Component Messages="messages"></Component>

@code {
    List<string> messages = new List<string>();

    protected async Task Run()
    {
        messages = new List<string>();

        await service.Run();
    }
}
```

**Component.razor component**

```cs
@using BlazorApp4.Data
@inject Messenger messenger

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Messages)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        messenger.OnMessageAdded += OnMessageAdded;
    }

    public async Task OnMessageAdded()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            Messages.Add(messenger.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(messenger.Message);
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        messenger.OnMessageAdded -= OnMessageAdded;
    }
}
```

So, if you go to **Parent.razor** and comment out the line 
`//messages = new List<string>();`
the program will work just fine, besides not clearing the list every time the button **RUN** is clicked.

Funny though, if you don't comment out this messages initialization line, and add a `await Task.Delay(1);` in the first line of the **Run()** method of the **Service** class, everything works fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What if you clear the list instead of create a new one at each run ? `messages.Clear()`

Comment: If you create a new List in your `Run` method, you are not rebinding the new list to your child component, you should call `StateHasChanged` in the `Run` method because the list reference changed.

Comment: That works indeed, honestly, I didn't think about doing that. However, do you know why creating a new one doesn't work? Thanks btw!

Comment: For the second comment, I tried running StateHasChanged in the Run method, but unsuccessfully

Comment: It doesn't work because the component is re rendered after the run completed, so the new child component has reference to the new empty list but events occur on the old one.